# Using Emacs TRAMP with an ssh server that doesn't provide /bin/sh?

Tags: android, emacs, ssh, tramp

I am trying to use Emacs TRAMP to access files over ssh on a server that does not provide `/bin/sh`, and so I get the following error when I try to connect:

```
env: can't execute '/bin/sh': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to tell TRAMP where the remote shell is for that server? (The "server" is a tethered Android phone, so sh in at `/system/bin/sh`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See also the docstring for the `tramp-methods` variable. This part would appear noteworthy:

> - `tramp-remote-shell`
>     This specifies the shell to use on the remote host.  This
>     MUST be a Bourne-like shell.  It is normally not necessary to
>     set this to any value other than "/bin/sh": Tramp wants to
>     use a shell which groks tilde expansion, but it can search
>     for it.  Also note that "/bin/sh" exists on all Unixen,
>     this might not be true for the value that you decide to use.
>     You Have Been Warned.

**Edit:**

So here's a way you could create a new method based on an existing one ("scpc" in this example), and then give the custom method a different remote shell:

```el
(require 'tramp)
(let* ((base-method (cdr (assoc "scpc" tramp-methods)))
       (new-method (copy-tree base-method))
       (rshell (assq 'tramp-remote-shell new-method)))
  (setcdr rshell "/system/bin/sh")
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods (cons "android" new-method)))
```

Note that in Emacs 23 (Tramp 2.1.20), this property was named `tramp-remote-sh`. In Emacs 24 (Tramp 2.2.3-24.1) it has been changed to `tramp-remote-shell`.

And I'm guessing that you can use this method by default for your specified host with this:

```el
(add-to-list
 'tramp-default-method-alist
 (list "\\`myhost\\'" nil "android"))
```

Comment: It looks like that sets the shell for all access via a given method (e.g. ssh). Is there any way to set this per-host?

Comment: You probably want to add a new method which uses the necessary tramp-remote-shell but is otherwise identical to the method you are basing it on, and then use that for accessing the host in question.

Comment: See also the `tramp-default-method-alist` variable, for mapping hosts to methods.

Comment: I'll probably end up adding a new method with the remote shell set.

Comment: I also have a problem with connecting with TRAMP over SSH to Android (2.2 on Samsung Galaxy S): not even with /bin/sh, but with "env" at an early stage -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs/+bug/1041474 . Another problem to treat in a method devised for connecting to Android over SSH.

Answer (score -1):

ssh expects to use the remote user's login shell. If you have root access to the server, you can change the entry in the passwd file:

:blah:blah:user_name:blah:/path/to/shell

Or just symlink /bin/sh to it.

I don't believe there is any way to change this from the client's side, but if there is, you would need to tell `ssh`, not TRAMP. (You could do this via an ssh_config file.)

Edit:
I stand corrected.

Comment: This is incorrect. @phils has explained it correctly; tramp uses the shell specified by `tramp-remote-shell`. It is also incorrect to say that you have to use ssh_config for anything like this as the program executing ssh can tell ssh which program to execute on the remote host on ssh's command line.